# SIP registration listener is not firing

Tags: android, callback, native, registration, sip

I have some problems with the native SIP registration in android. It seems that sometimes it registers properly without problems, but others it registers and deregisters and there are others that do nothing and never enters the callbacks.
Someone might give some clue of what I'm doing wrong?

I have the method initSIP() inside a Service, here it is:

```
private void initSIP()
{
    Toast.makeText(ctxt, "init SIP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if ((MyApplication)getApplication()).mSipManager == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    closeLocalProfile();

    SipProfile.Builder builder = null;
    try
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String phone = ((MyApplication)getApplication()).js_config.getString("sipuser");
        String pass = ((MyApplication)getApplication()).js_config.getString("sippass");

        builder = new SipProfile.Builder(phone, "127.0.0.1");
        builder.setPassword(pass);

        builder.setPort(5060);

        ((MyApplication)getApplication()).mSipProfile = builder.build();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);

        ((MyApplication)getApplication()).mSipManager.open(((MyApplication) getApplication()).mSipProfile, pendingIntent, null);

        ((MyApplication)getApplication()).mSipManager.setRegistrationListener(((MyApplication)getApplication()).mSipProfile.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener()
        {

            public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri)
            {
                Log.v("IncomingSipCallsService", "Registering with SIP Server...");
            }

            public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime)
            {
                Log.v("IncomingSipCallsService", "Ready");
                ((MyApplication)getApplication()).status_SIP = MyApplication.SIP_READY;
            }

            public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode, String errorMessage)
            {
                ((MyApplication)getApplication()).status_SIP = MyApplication.SIP_UNREADY;
                Log.v("SipCallsService", "Registration failed.  Please check settings.");
                Log.v("SipCallsService", "URI: " + localProfileUri + " ERROR: " + errorCode + " " + errorMessage);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(ctxt, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    catch (SipException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(ctxt, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(ctxt, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

On the server side we have Asterisk, and is constantly receiving "options" messages from the apps clients but a few "register" messages.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, when you develop an app, sometimes the Android native SIP service gets stuck and the registration listener is never fired. So, if any method of the listener is fired in 30 seconds, we opt to show a screen that requests the user to reboot his device.

We experienced it when we are developing the app and when you run the app in release mode with one signature and then with another one (for example, before and after setting up the release production signature). So, that shouldn't happen in the real world... but just in case, we decided to add that please reboot screen.